# Que error hay para hacer un Fourfold Plot con mi data

Tags: r

Quiero hacer lo mismo (con la data que esta al final) que con los ejemplos que voy a dar a continuación para ilustrar, pero cuando lo hago con mi data sale error. El paquete que se esta usando es `vcd` y los ejemplo son:

1)

```
UCB <- aperm(UCBAdmissions, c(2, 1, 3)) 
fourfold(UCB, mfrow = c(2, 3))
```

Sale esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2)

```
data("CoalMiners", package = "vcd") 
CM <- CoalMiners[, , 2 : 9] 
structable(. ~ Age, data = CM)
fourfold(CM, mfcol = c(2, 4))
```

sale esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando uso mi data que es

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cuando ya corro el mismo codigo anterior sale este error

```
fourfold(datos)
Error in fourfold(datos) : x must be an array
```

he pasado la columna x como factor pero sigue saliendo el mismo error

Comment: Seria ideal que agregaras los datos como texto, por ejemplo, agrega la salida de  `dput(datos)`, como adelanto, lo que muestras no parece ser una tabla de contingencia que es lo que espera `fourfold()`

Comment: x Prod Log CM DEE SIC NT CF GH Idi GI CTO
1   7           6   4    6   6  7  4  4 12 7   6
2   5           5   6    7   4  8  3  9 12 8   5
3   7           8   10    7  10  6  6  5  5 6 10
4   8           6    5    7   7  8  5  6  3 5 7
5   7           9    9    7   7  5 16 10  2 8 6